# calculate values

Tags: javascript, calculated-field

In an order form, each row has 3 fields: quantity, price, total.

How do I create a function that on changing a number the subtotal is calculated and so is the total?

Can anyone suggest a way?

Comment: What have you tried or how would you go about doing this? From there ppl are more apt to guide you

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to add a listener to each row so that when the price or quantity are updated, you can get the new quantity and price and update the total column.

In jQuery, something like:

```
$('.row').on('change', function() {
    var quantity = $('.quantity', this).val(), // get the new quatity
        price = $('.price', this).val(), // get the new price
        total = price*quantity;
    $('.total', this).val(total);  //set the row total

    var totals = $.map($('.row .total'), function(tot) {
        return tot.val(); // get each row total into an array
    }).reduce(function(p,c){return p+c},0); // sum them
    $('#total').val(totals); // set the complete total
});
```

This assumes that each order form row container has the class `row`, each quantity has the class `quantity`, each row total has the class `total` and the order form total has the id `total`.